# Git pull doesn't merge some files

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull

I try to pull from a remote.
Some files are correctly merged (with conflicts and so on), while others are completely untouched, i.e. the local version is kept also if the files in the repository I'm pulling from are very different.
Why the merge don't do anything on those files.

Comment: your question is very broad. you need to give way much more information if you want anyone to help you. Are you sure the files were changed on the remote on the same branch you are on locally? Please provide some output showing that you investigated this; and this will help us to understand the problem.

Comment: It's really very basic. Same branch (master) locally and on the remote. There are LOTS of files. Both remote and local have new commits from fork. Some files seem to be skipped completely from merge.

Comment: The thing is that with a basic setup most users don't run into this problem, so if we cannot reproduce it somehow; it is difficult to help you.

Comment: Without a way for us to reproduce your issue, all we can do is describe the general way that `git merge` works. It sounds to me like you're just looking at the two branch tip versions. You need to look as well at the merge base version of each file. Merge doesn't mean "combine files", it means "combine *changes* to files", and changes don't happen in a vacuum: there must be some common *starting* version of the file, before we can see *who* changed *what*.

Comment: Before doing the merge is there a way to check which files are different between my local version and the remote? I.e. to see the list of files that will be affected by the merge before doing the real merge?

Answer (score 0):

Using `git pull --rebase` could be the solution. Please ignore if you are already using this command.

Comment: This would be more suitable as a comment, not an answer, due to it's lack of certainly.

Comment: No actually I want to merge, not to rebase.